# Is this to a complementizer?

Tags: infinitives, complements

> “I don’t think what **to** name them,” Adam said.
>  (John
>   Steinbeck, East of Eden)

Is the *to* a complementizer leading the object of *think*; and *what*, the object of *name*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

‘There is no consensus regarding the application of the word “complementizer”  to makers of subordinate status that are inflectional (the genitive marker, *-ing*, and possibly *to*)’ says McCawley (1998, Ch. 5).

But the non-finite clause *what to name them* is certainly a complement (the direct object) of the verb *think*. Its subject “I” is deleted because it is identical with the subject of the main clause.

And *what* is one of the objects of the verb *name*. *Name* here is a bitransitive verb with two arguments in addition to the subject. There are two ways of thinking about those two arguments:

- You may think of *what* as the direct object (the name which is
  given) and of *them* as the indirect object (the recipient of the
  name). This interprets the clause as "I give them the name 'what'".
- You may think of *what* as a resultative object complement attributed
  to the object *them*. This interprets the clause as "I cause them to bear the name 'what'".

Use whichever analysis is most useful to whatever you want to do with the result.